# How to integrate PayPal in a C# application?

Tags: c#, paypal

I am confused by PayPal's developer info. I have a website. I want the User to be able to click the PayPal icon and when they made a payment the payment notification is sent to my URL.

I have created a button for this but I want the notification of payment to be sent to one of my URLs.

I also want to test this using a sandbox account. But after creating the sandbox account and I click 'create button' on the developers website it redirects me to the 'live' PayPal website where the construct of the button is as it was before.

I created a sandbox account and I have the criteria details.

Yet, despite much research I cannot find a simple easy to understand C# example of what I want to do.  One minute I am looking at their developers' BETA web site, the next I am looking at an example code on CodeProject that is four years old and not replicated in any of the examples I can see elsewhere.

Comment: You're not the only one. PayPal integration blows.

Comment: thanks. I am glad it is not just me :)

Comment: What are you working with?  Payments Standard, Express Checkout, or what?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am using Standard. I did come up with a solution using Form data. Thought the PayPal docs seem to indicate it is old and should not be used.  But it works for now so I am using it :)